Issues with creating and editing records in LoanTransaction model in ASP.NET Core
I’m working on an ASP.NET Core project with Entity Framework Core, and I'm facing issues with creating and editing records in the LoanTransaction model. Here's what I've done so far and the issues I’m encountering.
Problem Description
Create record: when trying to create a new LoanTransaction, the form submission does not work as expected. No record is added to the database, and there are no clear errors in the console.
Edit record: when trying to edit an existing LoanTransaction, the changes are not saved to the database, and again, there are no clear errors.
// Controller (LoanTransactionsController.cs)
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LoanProductManagementSystem.Data;
using LoanProductManagementSystem.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace LoanProductManagementSystem.Controllers
{
    public class LoanTransactionsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly LoanContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<LoanTransactionsController> _logger;

        public LoanTransactionsController(LoanContext context, ILogger<LoanTransactionsController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // GET: LoanTransactions
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var loanContext = _context.LoanTransactions
                .Include(l => l.Customer)
                .Include(l => l.LoanProduct);
            return View(await loanContext.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: LoanTransactions/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name");
            ViewData["LoanProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.LoanProducts, "LoanProductId", "ProductName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: LoanTransactions/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("LoanTransactionId,CustomerId,LoanProductId,Amount,Date")] LoanTransaction loanTransaction)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Add(loanTransaction);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "Error creating loan transaction");
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                }
            }

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name", loanTransaction.CustomerId);
            ViewData["LoanProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.LoanProducts, "LoanProductId", "ProductName", loanTransaction.LoanProductId);

            return View(loanTransaction);
        }

        // GET: LoanTransactions/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.LoanTransactions == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var loanTransaction = await _context.LoanTransactions.FindAsync(id);

            if (loanTransaction == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name", loanTransaction.CustomerId);
            ViewData["LoanProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.LoanProducts, "LoanProductId", "ProductName", loanTransaction.LoanProductId);

            return View(loanTransaction);
        }

        // POST: LoanTransactions/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("LoanTransactionId,CustomerId,LoanProductId,Amount,Date")] LoanTransaction loanTransaction)
        {
            if (id != loanTransaction.LoanTransactionId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(loanTransaction);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!LoanTransactionExists(loanTransaction.LoanTransactionId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name", loanTransaction.CustomerId);
            ViewData["LoanProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.LoanProducts, "LoanProductId", "ProductName", loanTransaction.LoanProductId);

            return View(loanTransaction);
        }

        private bool LoanTransactionExists(int id)
        {
            return (_context.LoanTransactions?.Any(e => e.LoanTransactionId == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}

View (Create.cshtml):
@model LoanProductManagementSystem.Models.LoanTransaction

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CustomerId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="CustomerId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(ViewData["CustomerId"] as SelectList)"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LoanProductId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="LoanProductId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(ViewData["LoanProductId"] as SelectList)"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="LoanProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Amount" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" type="date" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}

using System;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace LoanProductManagementSystem.Models
{
public class LoanTransaction
{
[Key]
public int LoanTransactionId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer is required")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Loan Product is required")]
    public int LoanProductId { get; set; }
    public LoanProduct LoanProduct { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Amount is required")]
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount must be a positive number")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

}
using LoanProductManagementSystem.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace LoanProductManagementSystem.Data
{
public class LoanContext : DbContext
{
public LoanContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
}
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LoanProduct> LoanProducts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LoanTransaction> LoanTransactions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasMany(c => c.LoanTransactions)
            .WithOne(t => t.Customer)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.CustomerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LoanProduct>()
            .HasMany(p => p.LoanTransactions)
            .WithOne(t => t.LoanProduct)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.LoanProductId);
    }
}

}
Error details:

No errors displayed: no specific errors are shown on the page or in the console.
No records added: the database does not seem to be updated with new records.

What I've tried:

Verified that the form fields are bound correctly
Checked that the database connection string is correct
Ensured that LoanTransaction model properties match the database schema

Can someone help me troubleshoot why creating and editing LoanTransaction records is not working as expected? Are there any common issues with EF Core migrations or form bindings that I might be missing?

What are your LoanTransactionmodel and dbcontext like? Is there any navigation configuration in your dbcontext or model? You can check whether the data is sent correctly in developer mode, and set a breakpoint on the Create method to check whether there is any relevant error information in ModelState.

@YuningDuan i just edit and added LoanTransactionmoded and dbcontext to the question

In the view bind the LoanTransaction model, but when submitting the form, the form only submits CustomerId and LoanProductId, resulting in the Customer and LoanProduct properties not being correctly bound. We can see that this causes the model validation to fail.

Solutions:
1.You can define the Customer and LoanProduct properties as nullable types in the LoanTransaction model
 public Customer? Customer { get; set; }

 public LoanProduct? LoanProduct { get; set; }

2.Remove the model state of these properties before model validation
`ModelState.Remove("Customer");`

`ModelState.Remove("LoanProduct");`

3.You can create a viewmodel to contain the required properties Model binding through viewmodel, such as：
public class LoanTransactionViewModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int LoanProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

View:
@model LoanTransactionViewModel
//some codes

Controller:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("LoanTransactionId,CustomerId,LoanProductId,Amount,Date")] LoanTransactionViewModel loanTransaction)
{
    //some codes

    return View(loanTransaction);
}


Similarly, these solutions can also be used in the Edit method

now it works! , the problem was indeed in my Loantransaction and nullable properties thanks so much for your help!
